# Missing Schema Error in connecting to mongodb database from node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am simply trying to add data to a collection in a mongodb database. I think technically I am trying to create a document in a new collection (the textbook I am using mentions CRUD (create, read, update, and delete). I am doing this with the npm - mongoose. Here is my code:

In a file called user.js (in a models folder)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model(("User", userSchema));

module.exports = User;
```

Then, in a file called 'test.js' in the app directory:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./models/user");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/my_database", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

User.create(
  {
    name: "Leon White",
    username: "lwhite",
    password: "password",
  },
  (error, user) => {
    console.log(error, user);
  }
);
```

The error I am getting is

```
"MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "[object Object]".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)"
```

I have checked and have it exactly as the textbook indicates and have looked at similar questions with this error code, but I can't figure out where in my code I have gone wrong. Any help?

Comment: Please, do not mix mysql with mongodb up! The two products are very different databases!

Comment: Thank you for that catch! Been a long day trying to figure out this problem. Had a brain fart.